# React State of Value Is Empty After Updating State In The ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get duration of a session using moment js based on state 
but the `calculateBill()` receives the initial state which was

```
state:{
   start:'',
   bill:''
}
```

I change The State here

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.setState({
  start:doc.data().start,
})
this.calculateBill();
}
```

I get the data from firestore well but the `calculateBill()` does not work it Returns `NaN`

```
calculateBill(){
let start = this.state.start;
let rate = 2;
let time = moment
        .duration(moment(moment().format('DDMMYYYY HH:mm'), 'DDMMYYYY HH:mm')
        .diff(moment(start, 'DDMMYYYY HH:mm'))
        ).asMinutes();
let calcBill = rate * time
let calc = calcBill.toString()

this.setState({
  bill:calc,
}); 
}
```

Comment: setState is asynchronous, therefor your update hasn*t completed yet

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Apologies if this isn’t precise, on my iPad... Either pass the doc.data().start value into the calculateBill function or add the function as a callback to set state. The callback only fires once setState has finished.  E.g. this.setState({
  start:doc.data().start,
}, this.calculateBill())